# laravel created two rows with exactly the same created time

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created an application with Laravel, the application has an `order` table and every user can insert one row into this table per request. I found in this table two rows that have exactly the same created_at time and they were created by the same user. How could he insert two rows with one request? Could anyone give me any tips about the problem? Thank you!

I have 2 table ,one is order, the other is mt_order which is belongs to order(the foregin key is order_id)

The code is below:

```php
    $orderData['consecutive_count'] = $count =  $user->getLatestConsecutiveCounts();
    $orderData['rate'] = $user->getRate($count);

    $orderData['lot'] = $orderData['base_lot'] * $orderData['rate'];//总手数
    $order = $user->orders()->create($orderData);

$group = $user->group;

    if($group->copy_type == 0)
    {
        if($type == 'buy')
        {
            $orderData['direct'] = 'sell';
        }
        else
        {
            $orderData['direct'] = 'buy';
        }
    }


    $mtorder = $order->mtorder()->create($orderData);
    $order->mt_order = $mtorder;

    return
    [
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $order,
    ];
```

I have an event for orderCreated, but seemds it do nothing，it doesn't have an listener.

```
public $order;
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        if($order->user->group->copy_type == 1)
        {
            $type = $order->direct;
        }
        else
        {
            $type = $order->direct == 'long' ? 'short' :'long';
        }

        $data = [
            'type' => 'exec', 
            'data' =>[
                'laravel_id' => $order->id,
                'MT_order_type' => $type, //多、空
                'MT_open_price' => $order->open_price,
                'MT_open_time' => $order->open_time,
                'MT_take_profit' => $order->take_profit,//(int)
                'MT_stop_loss' => $order->stop_loss,//int
            ],
        ];
        $this->order = $data;
    }
```

I triger the request with ajax like this

```
$(".buy-sell a").on('click', function(){
        let url = $(this).data('url');
        bootbox.confirm({
          message:'want to make order?',
          buttons: {
              confirm: {
                  label: 'confirm',
                  className: 'btn-success'
              },
              cancel: {
                  label: 'cancel',
                  className: 'btn-danger'
              }
         },
        　callback:function(result){
          if(result == true){
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type:'post',
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data.status)
                        {
                            let direct = data.data.direct == 1? '买入' :'卖出';
                            let str = '<ul class="list-inline" style="padding:10px"><li style="font-size:20px; color:#B7B7B7; width:100px">类型</li><li class="position-value">'+direct+'</li></ul> <ul class="list-inline" style="padding:10px"><li style="font-size:20px; color:#B7B7B7; width:100px">入场价格</li><li class="position-value" id="open_price">获取钟</li></ul><ul class="list-inline" style="padding:10px"><li style="font-size:20px; color:#B7B7B7; width:100px">入场时间</li><li class="position-value" id="open_time">获取中</li></ul>';

                            $("#current_position").empty().append(str);
                            $("#notes").remove();
                            view3.clear()
                            initData(0)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    },
                    complete:function(xhr, text)
                    {
                        if(xhr.status == 429)
                        {
                            alert('request too times');
                        }
                    }
                });
         }

       }
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no information for anyone to go off of, this is just a vague description of something random

Comment: because the user fast keep clicking the submit button, you need on the submit button add js on click `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: what if he use a robot emulate clicking the button?

Comment: after the first click, the submit button is change to disabled, how can click again

Comment: I mean he just uses some tools to directly request the url without clicking the button

Comment: first keep the created_at unique is very important ? may be on the register form you need to add recaptcha

Comment: good idea,thank you~

Comment: My personal opinion I wouldn't tackle it by setting the created_at unique, however unlikely if two different users hit submit at the same time one of them could receive an error. What I would do is check to see if the user making the request already has a row in the table, if they do, return out of the function. If they don't, create one.

Comment: @Mike Rodham, yes thats what i mean ref to OP  `two rows created by the same user`, so i mean checking same user unique created_at is very important ??, this not means the whole table column created_at unique ;)

Comment: You weren’t very specific in your comment as to what you meant so it wasn’t very clear what you wanted to be unique. A created_at time stamp shouldn’t be unique if multiple users can action the same request at any given time. But like I said, check to see if the user has a row in the table, if so, return from the function. If not, create one.

Comment: From the code you've provided it should only add one record - not two.
Can you provide some more code i.e. how is the request triggered - is it via javascript etc. - if so, perhaps you have two listeners for the same event, which sends two requests?

Comment: @kerby how do you know the user didn't send two requests?

Comment: I have edit the post and provide more code